# How to tell Cargo to use a git repository as source for an indirect dependency instead of crates.io?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

[A few days ago](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/compiling-to-the-web-with-rust-and-emscripten/7627), cross-compiling to JavaScript via Emscripten has finally hit nightly. I wanted to compile a project using `glium` in that manner. However, there are still many Emscripten-related bugs in many crates. While maintainers usually fix those bugs quickly, they don't necessarily release those bug fixes to [crates.io](https://crates.io/) immediately.

In my case, `glium` depends on `glutin`. `glutin` had a bug which is fixed now, but only in the git repository, not on `crates.io`.  *Note*: `glutin` is not a direct dependency of my project; only an indirect one through `glium`!

**How do I tell Cargo to use [the `glutin` repository](https://github.com/tomaka/glutin) as source for `glutin` instead of `crates.io`**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use **the `[patch]` section** in your project's `Cargo.toml`. For more information, check out [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html).

```toml
[patch.crates-io]
glutin = { git = 'https://github.com/tomaka/glutin' }
```

Comment: Is there a distinction between `"x:version.number" = ...` and `"x = { version = "version.number", ... }`?

Comment: @Jsor Yes, the latter doesn't work. The LHS defines *what* to replace and you can only replace specific versions of crates, not some crates in general (it may happen that you have two different versions of a crate in your dep-tree). The RHS says what to replace it *with* and as mentioned in the answer, the version has to match the LHS-version, so there is no point in writing it on the right side.

Comment: Note that `[replace]` is deprecated and `[patch]` should be used instead. See cargo docs linked in the answer for more.

Comment: I finally updated the answer to remove all mention of `[replace]` and just mention the `[patch]` solution. Thanks @kmdreko for the previous edit.