# How to make Cargo use a patch path for all nested dependencies during cargo build?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Cargo.toml as below:

```
[dependencies]
a = "x.x.x"
b = "y.y.y"
c = "z.z.z"
```

There is a local change made in dependency `a`, hence updated above manifest to use the local path using

```
a = { path = "/mypath" }
```

This works fine and `a` picks up the correct code however `b` and `c` also have `a` in their Cargo.toml as dependency pointing to the same "x.x.x" version and `cargo build` fails again.

Is there a way to tell Cargo to always use `/mypath` whenever it comes across `a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell Cargo to use a git repository as source for an indirect dependency instead of crates.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070903/how-to-tell-cargo-to-use-a-git-repository-as-source-for-an-indirect-dependency-i)

Comment: Nope, the above link shows how to resolve the single dependency. My question is for large package with nested dependencies within sub-dependencies which all might depend on a single "a" and I need Cargo to always use local "a" when any dependency hits it.